# How to restore umlaute or special characters in python 3 after recieving them from email message object?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, email, unicode

I have a python class for reading out emails from gmail. I can recieve the emails fine, however after getting the emails with this exemplary commands:

```
import email

#...
s = self.message.get_payload()
message = s[0].get_payload()
```

I face the problem that characters like Umalaute are not shown properly,e.g:

```
"Weiterer Tests für Email-Empfang"
```

gets shown as:

```
"Weiterer Test f=C3=BCr Email-Empfang"
```

I know that in Python 3 all strings are unicode by default, but how can I restore the original message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=C3=B3` is the ascii representation of the UTF-8 encoding, which is used in URLS. So, you can use `urllib.parse.unquote`:

```
>>> s = "Weiterer Test f=C3=BCr Email-Empfang"
>>> unquote(s.replace("=", "%"))
'Weiterer Test für Email-Empfang'
>>> s = "Weiterer Test f%C3%BCr Email-Empfang"
>>> unquote(s.replace('=', '%'))
'Weiterer Test für Email-Empfang'
```

Comment: Won't this break if the input contains "%"? Isn't the [quopri module](https://docs.python.org/library/quopri.html) a better fit for this kind of escaping?

Comment: @lenz It works if you replace the `=` with `%` in the OP's question. Do you have an example of when it doesn't work?

Comment: Downvote: This somehow gets the job done for your specific example, but is based on a *very* superficial understanding of the problem. This is not "URL encoding" although it is conceptually similar. Proper parsing of email requires understanding MIME and specifically here the various RFC2047 encodings and how to know which one was used.

Comment: In case it's not blazingly obvious, a literal `%` in a URL gets encoded as `%25`; and a literal `=` in quoted printable encoding is `=3D`

Comment: @rassar: Decode `"Abz=C3=BCge: %40"` so that `%40` is still present in the output.

Comment: @tripleee You're right, I totally misjudged the question. If you want to post an answer, go ahead and I'll delete this one. I actually don't know how to decode RFC so I won't change my answer.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is already in a comment above. If you have the reputation to second it, there will be a "close" link under the question's tags.